# DXA 1.7 JAVA application setup error

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

I am trying to set up the DXA 1.7 Java application. I followed the below steps. After the set up when I tried to run the application I got the below error.

Steps Followed:
1. Downloaded the source code from https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/master/dxa-webapp - Version 1.7

2. Created Maven project using the POM.xml which is available in dxa-webapp
3. Updated the discovery service URL and Token service's ClientId and ClientSecret in cd_client_config.xml
4. Rebuilt the application and Ran the application

Error Received:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: The service is not available and cache does not contain value for query: ODataClientQuery[GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://localhost:8080/dxa-webapp/dxa-webapp/dxa-webapp/')]
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.ContentClient.getFromCache(ContentClient.java:222)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.ContentClient.getEntity(ContentClient.java:172)
    at com.sdl.web.api.dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.getPublicationMapping(DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.java:27)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.getPublicationMappingData(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:20)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.getLocalization(AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.java:61)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.localization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:339)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.getLocalization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:171)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2bfec188.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$94921ba9.getLocalization(<generated>)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.markup.MarkupImpl.versionedContent(MarkupImpl.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:158)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.invoke(JasperELResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Views.Shared.Error.ServerError_jsp._jspService(ServerError_jsp.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Do you have DXA properly installed on the CMS and is everything published as described in the documentation? The web application cannot run alone, it requires a fully functioning backend. This all relates back to what is available in the discovery service (Topology) and in the broker storage. You really need to provide more detail in your question, as an error message by itself doesn't say much more than you don't have a connection to the content service.

Comment: Did you ever find out the cause and fix for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the `README.md` file in the repository (https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/release/1.7) it points to the documentation in the SDL documentation portal: http://docs.sdl.com/sdldxa17

There is a topic Installing SDL Digital Experience Accelerator (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-8E88E5AF-4552-40F0-8DB2-FBDBDBA41A11) in there, which if you follow it step by step should bring you further.

Without knowing exactly what you have done, there is also no way for us to know what steps you have missed. In case this documentation doesn't help you any further, I suggest you **edit** your question with some more details so an updated answer can be provided.

Last, might I mention that the latest release of DXA is currently the 2.0 version, so you might actually want to get started with that.

Comment: Thank you Bart. The DXA have been installed already. So I will recheck the installation.

Comment: Hi Bart Updated my question.